# Enterprise Library "Procedure or Function Expects Parameter Which Was Not Supplied" Error

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, enterprise-library

I realize there are quite a few others having posted similar questions, but I can't seem to find one quite on point.

I have a simple stored procedure performing an insert:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CategoryTreeInsert]
   @CategoryId Int,
   @InvenexNodeId Int,
   @ParentNodeId Int,
   @NodeId Int,
   @Node nvarchar(max),
   @NodeQuery nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO dbo.CategoryTree(
                CategoryId,
                InvenexNodeId,
                ParentNodeId,
                NodeId,
                Node,
                NodeQuery
                )VALUES(
                @CategoryId,
                @InvenexNodeId,
                @ParentNodeId,
                @NodeId,
                @Node,
                @NodeQuery
                )

                IF @@ERROR <> 0
                    BEGIN
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                        Return -1
                    END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    COMMIT TRANSACTION
                    RETURN 1
                END
END
```

I'm calling this procedure out of a class library using the Enterprise Data Access Application Block as follows.

(Note: I'd ordinarily use a `SqlParameter[]` rather than this method, but this was supposed to be a "quick and dirty")

```
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CategoryTreeInsert");
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryId",SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["CategoryId"]));
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvenexNodeId",SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["InvenexNodeId"]));
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParentNodeId",SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["ParentNodeId"]));
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@NodeId",SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["NodeId"]));
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Node", Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["Node"]);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NodeQuery", Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["NodeQuery"]);

Database Db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DefaultConnection");
Db.ExecuteNonQuery(Cmd);
```

The error being returned is

> Procedure or Function Expects Parameter "@CategoryId" Which Was Not Supplied

I've got a watch on the `SqlCommand` "Cmd", as well as all the parameter values, which appear to be properly named, typed and populated.

I'm figuring this has got to be something relatively simple that a fresh eye could point out quickly.

Can anybody help?

Thanks so much in advance!

**EDIT: Solution**

As Sriram noted, I had placed the intended parameter value improperly in the overload.

The corrected code is as follows:

```
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CategoryTreeInsert");
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryId",SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters["@CategoryId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["CategoryId"]);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvenexNodeId",SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters["@InvenexNodeId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["InvenexNodeId"]);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParentNodeId",SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters["@ParentNodeId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["ParentNodeId"]);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@NodeId",SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters["@NodeId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["NodeId"]);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Node", Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["Node"]);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NodeQuery", Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["NodeQuery"]);

            Database Db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DefaultConnection");
            Db.ExecuteNonQuery(Cmd);
```

Thanks so much for the insanely quick reply Sriram!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryId",SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["CategoryId"]));
```

In above line you're using the following overload of add

```
public SqlParameter Add(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType, int size);
```

as you can see you're passing `CategoryId` in `size` parameter and hence this fails.

You need something like this

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@CategoryId",SqlDbType.Int);
param.Value = Dt.Rows[CurrentRow]["CategoryId"];
Cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Also you're missing same thing in InvenexNodeId,ParentNodeId,NodeId parameters as well.

Comment: Perfect...I can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parameters.AddWithValue method